# How do i access series width and height parameters when using Ag Charts?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Here's a plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/1JKSFKykiObxDYJR?open=main.js&preview

Note in console when logging chart object itself `seriesRect` property is there, but when accessing it directly or with `getSeriesRect()` method it's undefined.

How come?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because seriesReact may not be defined until the chart is rendered. Once the chart is rendered the property of chart will update so thats why you can see the proper value in there instead of undefined. If you want to console.log or store the value of seriesRect somewhere you can try this approach using an interval or you might me able to use an eventListener on the chart to check when that chart has rendered and only then try to access the seriesRect property:

```
/** @type {import('ag-charts-community').AgChartOptions} */
const options = {
  container: document.getElementById('myChart'),
  title: {
    text: "Apple's revenue by product category",
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'in billion U.S. dollars',
  },
  data: getData(),
  series: [
    {
      type: 'column',
      xKey: 'quarter',
      yKey: 'iphone',
    },
  ],
};

const chart = agCharts.AgChart.create(options);
console.log(
  '[DEBUG] Series dims access with method',
  chart.chart.getSeriesRect()
);

console.log('[DEBUG] chart object', chart.chart);
const checkSeriesRectInterval = setInterval(() => {
  if (chart.chart.seriesRect) {
    console.log('[DEBUG] seriesRect found:', chart.chart.seriesRect);
    clearInterval(checkSeriesRectInterval);
  } else {
    console.log('[DEBUG] seriesRect not found, retrying...');
  }
}, 100); // Check for seriesRect every 100 milliseconds
```